# How to call a method in the __init__ method of a class in order to make a QPushButton custom widget

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

Here is the basic code:

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap

class CategoryButton(QPushButton):
    
    def __init__(self, icon: QPixmap, text: str) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self._icon      = icon
        self._text      = text

        self.Draw()

    def Draw(self) -> QPushButton:
        button_layout   = QHBoxLayout()
        label_icon      = QLabel()
        label_text      = QLabel(self._text)

        label_icon.setPixmap(self._icon)

        button_layout.addWidget(label_icon)
        button_layout.addStretch(1)
        button_layout.addWidget(label_text)
        button_layout.addStretch(1)

        button = QPushButton()
        button.setLayout(button_layout)

        return button

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')

    h = CategoryButton(QPixmap("app/src/view/assets/icons/account.svg"), "account")
    h.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It shows the button but not with the icon and the text. This custom button is basically to have an icon on the left and at the center of what is left, to have descriptive text.

The only way I got it to work like is by changing the main function to this:

```py
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')

    h = CategoryButton(QPixmap("app/src/view/assets/icons/account.svg"), "account").Draw()
    h.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

adding .Draw() at the end of "h=...".
I dont want to add .Draw( at the end of every custom widget all the time since it isnt very PySide like, there is probably an easy solution and I am just oblivious. Thank you in advance

Comment: It doesn't work because you're creating a new button, which doesn't make any sense, since you're already in a new QPushButton instance. You should just use `self.setLayout()`, withou creating a new button. Besides, can you explain why you're trying to do so? QPushButton already supports showing icons and text, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes I know but when you have multiple buttons with icons and texts of different lengths, the icons arent alligned, here they would be alligned.